# Finding a primary key

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a big dataset with 4.5 million rows and 150 columns. I want to create a table in my database, and I want to create an index for it.

There isn't a column with ids and  I would like to know if there is an easy way to find a column or combination of columns that could be unique to base my index on those.

I am using python and pandas

Comment: Pandas should automaically create an index for you if you did not specify one so you could use `df.index` or set the index on multiple columns using `set_index`

Comment: You could go through the columns in turn and call `.drop_duplicates()` and compare the number of rows before and after this to determine if the column values are unique